# Fade-in & Fade-out effect on a menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to add a fade-in/fade-out effect to the menu on [this website](http://ctu.ctuproject.com/). How might I go about accomplishing this? Thanks in advance for any help.

I dont know why this is so hard to do, I want something very simple. Every item in my menu has their own items in it and on hover position they shows what they have in it, I want to open that menu with a effect.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: Wow, `Donut` really did some editing magic on this question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ELEMENT HERE").fadeTo("slow", 0.3);
    $("ELEMENT HERE").hover(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1.0);},function(){
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.3);
    });
});
```

Here is an [example](http://www.hv-designs.co.uk/tutorials/jquery/div.html).

You can find more information about [FadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [FadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).

Comment: Could I reccomend having .stop() to stop queuing the animations all together?